# Display UIImage with an image from a URL

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimage

I am trying to display a list of items. My end game is displaying a grid of images from an array of Strings that are URLs and file names on my IOS app.

I have a CollectionView that is displaying a grid of images via an array of String filenames, and that works:

Array:

```
var tableImages: [String] = ["car.jpg", "bus.jpg", "plane.jpg"]
```

code that works:

```
cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(named: tableImages[indexPath.row])
```

My next step is figuring out the code for displaying a grid of images via an array of String urls. And that is my question. How do I display an image from a url?

Array:

```
var tableImages: [String] = ["http://www.hotelstmarie.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/HSM_Guest-Rooms_1500x750-06-02-2015.jpg", "http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/4f/b0/58/aviva-by-kameel.jpg"]
```

code that works:

```
?
```

**Notes:**

I have checked other stackoverflow questions on the matter but they are from years ago and the move to swift has made their answers out of date.

After I figure out how to display url images I will just make some if statements to recognize url or filename to make it to my endgame, but that is not part of this question.

**EDIT 1**

Code around my code above:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: CollViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollViewCell
    cell.labelCell.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
    cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(named: tableImages[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Using Alamofire:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: CollViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollViewCell
    cell.labelCell.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
    let imageUrl = NSURL(string: tableImages[indexPath.row])
    cell.imgCell.af_setImageWithUrl(imageUrl, placeholderImage: nil, filter: nil, imageTransition: .CrossDissolve(0.2))
    return cell
}
```

Gives this error:

```
Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'af_setImageWithUrl'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are setting your image here:

```
cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(named: tableImages[indexPath.row])
```

Only works for local images in your project, so your all will try to look for an image named the same as your url locally.

While you could load the image manually, the best alternative is to use an image loading library to deal with common issues, like avoiding old images to load on top of your new ones when your view gets recycled.

In swift i have used `AlamofireImage` like so:

```
let imageUrl = NSURL(string: tableImages[indexPath.row])
cell.imgCell.af_setImageWithURL(imageUrl, placeholderImage: nil, filter: nil, imageTransition: .CrossDissolve(0.2))
```

as you can see, this library uses swift's `extensions` which greatly simplifies it's api.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just tried it, can you see my edit 2?

Comment: @Rorschach At the top of your file you need to add `import AlamofireImage` to your project. Here's a link to the repo with install instructions: https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage (it uses either Cocoapods or Carthage)

Comment: @Rorschach my bad, i misspelled the method name (i typed `af_setImageWithUrl` and it was `af_setImageWithURL`). I Edited my answer with the correct method.

Answer (score 2):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: CollViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollViewCell
    cell.labelCell.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

    if let url = NSURL(string: tableImages[indexPath.row])
    {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
        {
            cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would write:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: tableImages[indexPath.row]){
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
    cell.imgCell.image = image
}
```

Although I recommend using an existing Swift library (like [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)) that handles thread management and caching for you, so your app doesn't run out of memory or freeze while it's downloading the images.  I currently use [SDWebImage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28906189/4834558).

Comment: This goes through with no errors, but no images are being displayed, Ill work with my code and see whats up and accept this answer if it ends up leading me to the answer

Comment: @Rorschach The problem *could* be that the images are just taking a while to download.  If it is, you're better off using one of the libraries I mentioned, or others (like Alamofire) :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used Swift version of UIImageView+AFNetworking from AFNetworking library which you can get from [github](https://github.com/namanhams/Swift-UIImageView-AFNetworking). Very easy to use. Just drop the file in your project and you can start using it as following:

```
   cell.imageView.setImageWithUrl(imageUrl!,placeHolderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
```