# Show Images table view controller with the Library AlamofireImage Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I'm making an app that works as a reader.

I have a `UITableViewController` , which show all the news I read a xml, show the title, date, a brief description and a picture. Less image, I show everything right.

I added the AlamofireImage library for images to be displayed. At first they do not appear, but if I charge a `reloadData()` view, the images appear.

Most of the images are in the correct position , but others out of position and some , just out image. The title, date and description or shown.

I leave the code I use:

```
if let actualImageView = imageView {
  actualImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

  let URL = NSURL(string: currentArticleToDisplay.imagen)!
  actualImageView.af_setImageWithURL(
     URL,
     placeholderImage: nil,
     filter: nil
  )
}
```

The constraints , I have them defined in the Main.storyboard , because if you put them in code , either charged me at first .

Any idea what could be the problem? Do I need to add more parts of the code ? Is this the correct way to display images ? Is there any library with which it can solve ?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Faster way to load image from an URL to image view in table view cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905647/faster-way-to-load-image-from-an-url-to-image-view-in-table-view-cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SDWebimage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Similar questions

[loading tableView images asynchronously in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324459/loading-tableview-images-asynchronously-in-swift/31286596#31286596)

[Faster way to load image from an URL to image view in table view cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905647/faster-way-to-load-image-from-an-url-to-image-view-in-table-view-cell)